# GSM - RFC for GSM protocol

Tags: rfc

I'm working on [OpenBTS](http://openbts.org) source code and I need to know if there's any [RFC](https://www.ietf.org/standards/rfcs/) documentation out there for GSM protocol to study?

I googled it, but there's no specific RFC for GSM protocol itself.

Specifically, I'm studying GSM encryption protocol stack but I need to be familiar to the protocol itself.

Anyone helping?

Comment: Unfortunately, product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic for SE sites, except [softwareerecs.se] and [hardwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IETF doesn't normally have RFCs for layer-1/2 protocols. For example, the IEEE maintains LAN protocols (ethernet, token ring, Wi-Fi, etc.), and the standards for those are in the IEEE working group numbers (802.3, 802.5, 802.11, etc.) from the IEEE.

GSM was created by ETSI. It may be that you must buy the the standard from the GSM Association, or become a member to get a copy of the standard.